# How should the GridView/ListView with images be handled to avoit memory leaks, if any?

Tags: android, out-of-memory, android-gridview, android-adapter

Scenario:

- A `Fragment`
- A `gridview` which displays images from external-storage/downloads from the web
- An `Adapter` for the `gridview` which uses an xml layout containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView` inside a `FrameLayout`
- Inside `getView` the adapter downloads the image and sets it as resource for the bitmap

After the user is done with the fragment, the fragment is removed.

My concern:
We all know that android is prone to OoM errors, especially when working with bitmaps, even if when they are scaled down.
When the fragment is removed, like `onPause` should I parse all the items of the `GridView` and:

- remove callbacks for image drawable
- recyle the bitmpa drawable ?

Is this needed to prevent memory leaks ?

Comment: I would take a look at lazy-loading the images with something like this: http://androidexample.com/Download_Images_From_Web_And_Lazy_Load_In_ListView_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=112&aaid=134  It should handle all of the stuff you're worried about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, my main concern was related to usage of already scaled down bitmaps, but in the same time handling a lot of memory caching of other images. This could be a problem for instance on big screen devices, where an image can be scaled to 1080px and its footprint in memory is not small. I also had to stack some fragments containing images for future use. 
This forced the app to run into out of memory after a while. The fix I applied for now is to allow large memory use by `android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#CheckHowMuchMemory : Using the extra memory will increasingly be to the detriment of the overall user experience because garbage collection will take longer and system performance may be slower when task switching or performing other common operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a full size image, I recommend you to use sampled images.

```
  options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize();
  options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
```

And I use the following tricky code in my own project on decoding files to bitmaps.

```
  public static Bitmap decodeFile(String pathName, BitmapFactory.Options opts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      try {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, opts);
      }
      catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        System.gc();// Retry with running gc.
      }
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName, opts);
  }
```

Comment: System.gc(); doesn't force the system to garbage collect immediately, and the JVM can even ignore it, so immediately trying to decode it again outside of the try/catch after it's failed will almost definitely result in the same OutOfMemoryError being thrown again. He's way better off calculating the inSampleSize before decoding it so that he doesn't (or, more accurately, is far less likely to) run into the issue in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not about how I load the images, but how to manage them when the list gets destroyed.